# Login loop when rotating display in Ubuntu 22.04 X11

Tags: xorg, amd-graphics, 22.04, display-rotation

I just updated to 22.04 and I got into a login loop.
After clearing `~/.config/monitors.xml`, I narrowed down the problem to one of my monitors being rotated.

- I'm using 3 monitors: landscape (Samsung 22"), portrait (Dell 24"), landscape (Dell 24").
- GPU is HD 6770, Radeon driver
- I'm using X11 because it's so much easier to share screen in Chrome.
- After deleting `monitors.xml` I can log back in, but as soon as I rotate one of my monitors, I get logged out and I have to delete the file again.
- Switched back to Wayland, and I can rotate my screens without problems, just have to deal with the hassle of share screening.

Any help, or ideas to try are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same issue exists under Xubuntu 22.04.
In my case, the GPU is a Radeon HD 7700.
However, deleting the display configuration for xfce4 `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` does not temporarily solve the problem.